# Android application to limit websites access via HotSpot network

Tags: android, wifi, dns

I will open free wifi networks in taxis. I'll put an Android tablet in the taxi to show advertisements and share free internet access point.

When I install the application on the tabled and share wifi from it, I want people only to access predefined websites and block all other websites.

I found android applications and libraries that filters domains on the same device, but they don't block websites that are connected to the tablet shared wifi from accessing the websites.

Is there an android application or library that allows me to filter wifi domains and allow only predefined domains to work on a **Hotspot wifi network**?